# Is there a way to add different shapes depending on different data to my force-directed graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, symbols

I'm sure this has been covered in another question on here however, after trying many different examples on my code i cannot seem to get this to work.

I am trying to make the nodes on my force-directed graph a different shape depending on the name of the node, for example, if the node is named 'Switch' it should be displayed as a square.

I have worked out the set up for changing the colour of the nodes based on the data and would like a similar thing for the shape but can't get it to work using d3.v4.

Any help?

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
var shape = d3.symbolTypes;

var node = g.append("g")
 .attr("class", "nodes")
 .selectAll("circle")
 .data(graph.nodes)
 .enter().append("circle")
 .attr("r", 15)
 .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
 .attr("d", d3.symbol()
   .type(function (d) { return shape(d.name);}))
 .call(d3.drag()
 .on("start", dragstarted)
 .on("drag", dragged)
 .on("end", dragended));
```

Many Thanks

Faye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use:

```
var shape = d3.symbolTypes;
....
shape(d.name);
```

since `d3.symbolTypes` is not defined in d3 v4 (it was in some versions of v3), in v4 use `d3.symbols` which is an array not a function.

But, as with color, you could create an ordinal scale for shape:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
var shape = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.symbols);
```

Now all you have to do is append that shape:

```
.append('path')
     .attr("d", d3.symbol().type( function(d) { return shape(d[property]);} ) );
```

Since you were appending circles, and are now appending paths, you'll need to change `.append('circle')`, and as circles have `cx` `cy` elements, you need to change to a transform where you set their position.

Here is a [bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/24a5ddaab5e2756fbc029dccc1da3f8b) which should show this in practice, based on MBostock's force directed graph ([here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045))

Keep in mind there are only seven shapes in the `d3.symbols` array.

Edit:
If you want to specify which shapes get displayed for each node based on a property (rather than letting the ordinal scale set the shape), you could add a property to your data which contains the name of a shape (eg: `d3.symbolCross`), or create a function which takes in a data value and outputs the name of a symbol. But an ordinal scale is easiest.

Comment: Ahh right, i see where i was going wrong with it now. Thank you very much for your help, you have solved my problem.

Comment: node.append("text") Just doesnt work to display the name/id for the node when d3.symbols is in use. Do you have a solution for that ?